# Find which element (row and column) that differ between two data frames in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse

Is there a simple way to find which element (row and column) that differ between two data frames in R? I know I can get which rows are different using `setdiff()` or `dplyr::anti_join()`. I also know it is possible using other software, but I’d like to know if I can do this inside R (or RStudio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `waldo` library.

```
> library(waldo)
> a = data.frame(x=1:3, y=c("a", "b", "c"))
> b = data.frame(x=1:3, y=c("a", "B", "c"))
> compare(a, b)
old vs new
           y
  old[1, ] a
- old[2, ] b
+ new[2, ] B
  old[3, ] c

`old$y`: "a" "b" "c"
`new$y`: "a" "B" "c"
```

Comment: `waldo` is cool but in simple examples like that I prefer the output of `which(a!=b, arr.ind=T)`.